# Retrieve variable from previous for-each statement

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've looked everywhere and have played with this XSLT code for days, but I just can't figure this one out. I'll try my best to explain because this is a complex issue. The file has to be summarized by account and department, then have an offset line to summarize by just department (shown in the output below).

The *wd:Earning_Code = 'FLSA-01'* has an incorrect *wd:Department*. The *wd:Earning_Code = 'FLSA-01'* transaction amount should be tied back into the *wd:Earning_Code = 'OT'*. The problem is that there can be multiple departments on the OT earning code.

I have to sum the total *FLSA* earning and *Overtime* earning *Amount* by the position, then divide by the total hours on the OT earning by the position. I then divide the amount by hours to get an hourly rate, an multiple this rate to the OT hours into the appropriate department. This all works on the summarize by account and department, but not on the summarize by department part. I have simplified the XML and XSL the best I can below..

Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/bsvc">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Emplid>831186318</wd:Emplid>
        <wd:Ledger_ID>2325</wd:Ledger_ID>
        <wd:Earning_Code>OT</wd:Earning_Code>
        <wd:Total_PayLine_hours>8.25</wd:Total_PayLine_hours>
        <wd:Position>P111827</wd:Position>
        <wd:Transaction_Amount>203.61</wd:Transaction_Amount>
        <wd:Department>2002000</wd:Department>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Emplid>831186318</wd:Emplid>
        <wd:Ledger_ID>6767</wd:Ledger_ID>
        <wd:Earning_Code>SALARY</wd:Earning_Code>
        <wd:Total_PayLine_hours>8.25</wd:Total_PayLine_hours>
        <wd:Position>P111827</wd:Position>
        <wd:Transaction_Amount>100</wd:Transaction_Amount>
        <wd:Department>2002000</wd:Department>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Emplid>831186318</wd:Emplid>
        <wd:Ledger_ID>2325</wd:Ledger_ID>
        <wd:Earning_Code>FLSA-01</wd:Earning_Code>
        <wd:Total_PayLine_hours>8.25</wd:Total_PayLine_hours>
        <wd:Position>P111827</wd:Position>
        <wd:Transaction_Amount>132.79</wd:Transaction_Amount>
        <wd:Department>2002000</wd:Department>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Emplid>342441735</wd:Emplid>
        <wd:Ledger_ID>2387</wd:Ledger_ID>
        <wd:Earning_Code>OT</wd:Earning_Code>
        <wd:Total_PayLine_hours>2</wd:Total_PayLine_hours>
        <wd:Position>P114386</wd:Position>
        <wd:Transaction_Amount>86.8</wd:Transaction_Amount>
        <wd:Department>2002000</wd:Department>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Emplid>342441735</wd:Emplid>
        <wd:Ledger_ID>2387</wd:Ledger_ID>
        <wd:Earning_Code>OT</wd:Earning_Code>
        <wd:Total_PayLine_hours>8</wd:Total_PayLine_hours>
        <wd:Position>P114386</wd:Position>
        <wd:Transaction_Amount>347.2</wd:Transaction_Amount>
        <wd:Department>2049000</wd:Department>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Emplid>342441735</wd:Emplid>
        <wd:Ledger_ID>2387</wd:Ledger_ID>
        <wd:Earning_Code>FLSA-01</wd:Earning_Code>
        <wd:Total_PayLine_hours>10</wd:Total_PayLine_hours>
        <wd:Position>P114386</wd:Position>
        <wd:Transaction_Amount>311.44</wd:Transaction_Amount>
        <wd:Department>2943000</wd:Department>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Emplid>342441735</wd:Emplid>
        <wd:Ledger_ID>6767</wd:Ledger_ID>
        <wd:Earning_Code>SALARY</wd:Earning_Code>
        <wd:Total_PayLine_hours>10</wd:Total_PayLine_hours>
        <wd:Position>P114386</wd:Position>
        <wd:Transaction_Amount>200</wd:Transaction_Amount>
        <wd:Department>2049000</wd:Department>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Below is my XSL:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" 
        xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/bsvc">
        <xsl:output indent="no" method="text"/>
        <xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">
            <header>
                <xsl:text>Account</xsl:text><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>Department</xsl:text><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>Amount</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            </header>
         <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry[ wd:Earning_Code != 'FLSA-01']" group-by="wd:Department">
                        <xsl:variable name="Department" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="wd:Ledger_ID">
                            <!-- Ledger ID --><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" /><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                            <!-- Dept ID --><xsl:value-of select="$Department"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>

                            <!-- The Department on the wd:Earning_Code = 'FLSA-01' is incorrect. I will sum FLSA and OT amount, then divide by the OT hours. Tie back using OT department.-->

                            <!-- Sum of OT hours by Position -->
                            <xsl:variable name="SumOfOvertimeHours" select="sum(../wd:Report_Entry[wd:Earning_Code = 'OT'  and wd:Position = current-group()/wd:Position]/wd:Total_PayLine_hours)"/>

                            <!-- To get the Sum Amount of OT and FLSA by position-->
                            <xsl:variable name="OverTimeandFLSAAmount" select="sum(../wd:Report_Entry[(wd:Ledger_ID = '2325' or wd:Ledger_ID  ='2387') and (wd:Position = current-group()/wd:Position) ]/wd:Transaction_Amount )"/>

                            <!-- To get Hourly Rate for all of Overtime and FLSA-->
                            <xsl:variable name="OTHourlyRate" select="$OverTimeandFLSAAmount div $SumOfOvertimeHours"/>

                            <!-- To get the Sum of OT and FLSA to tie Department. Use Hourly rate * hours from OT-->
                            <xsl:variable name="LedgerAmount" select="format-number($OTHourlyRate * sum(current-group()[wd:Earning_Code = 'OT']/wd:Total_PayLine_hours),'##.00')"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$LedgerAmount"/>
                            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>    

    <!-- *****************************************************Offset************************************************************************************** -->                
                                <!-- Ledger ID --><xsl:text>Balance</xsl:text><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                                <!-- Dept ID --><xsl:value-of select="$Department"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>

                                 <!-- Sum of OT hours by Position -->
                                 <xsl:variable name="SumOfOTHours" select="sum(../wd:Report_Entry[wd:Earning_Code = 'OT'  and wd:Position = current-group()/wd:Position]/wd:Total_PayLine_hours)"/>

                                <!-- Sum of OT and FLSA amount by Position -->
                                <xsl:variable name="SumOfOTandFLSAAmount" select="sum(../wd:Report_Entry[( (wd:Ledger_ID = '2387' or wd:Ledger_ID = '2325' )  and wd:Position = current-group()/wd:Position)]/wd:Transaction_Amount)"/>

                                <!-- To get Hourly Rate for all of Overtime and FLSA-->
                                <xsl:variable name="OTHourlyRate" select="$SumOfOTandFLSAAmount div $SumOfOTHours"/>

                                <!-- To get the Sum of OT and FLSA to tie Department. Use Hourly rate * hours from OT-->
                                <xsl:value-of select="number(format-number($OTHourlyRate * sum(../wd:Report_Entry[wd:Earning_Code = 'OT' and wd:Department = $Department ]/wd:Total_PayLine_hours),'##.00'))"/>

                                <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>               
                    </xsl:for-each-group>  
        </xsl:template>   
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my output. The *Balance* for the *2002000 Department* is not the right amount. It should be `585.49` and not `607.61`:

```
    Account|Department|Amount
    2325|2002000|336.40
    2387|2002000|149.09
    Balance|2002000|607.61
    2387|2049000|596.35
    Balance|2049000|596.35
```

Is it possible to just COPY the *LedgerAmount* variable from the parent for-each statement and match by department?? Or is there another method?

Any help is very much appreciated!!!
Thank you, -Remo

Comment: You have quite a bit of conditionals in the XSLT making it a tough read when initial XML looks to be a straightforward aggregation.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately it's one of those very weird scenarios that I have to account for. I'm not expecting anyone to solve this one, but it's worth a try lol. I've simplified this more. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Try simplifying it even more. Remove everything that's not necessary to demonstrate the current problem.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I've removed some more things. If I take anything else off, it won't show the issue. Is there any way to copy the LedgerAmount variable from the parent for-each statement and match by department?

Comment: I haven't understood all the conditions but if you want to store result of previous computations to compute aggregates like a sum then you could store the results in an XML structure first instead of outputting text directly. Additionally, assuming you use an XSLT 2 processor like Saxon 9 or Altova for which now also updated versions exist that support XSLT 3 you could use `xsl:iterate` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-iterate) instead of `xsl:for-each` as `xsl:iterate` allows you to pass on parameters from each previous iteration step.

Comment: See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUw as an attempt to store an intermediary result of the "inner" groups and then use them for summing up the amounts. Not sure whether any values are right, so for the time I post it as a comment.

Comment: Martin, what you did solved the problem. Thank you soo much! How do I give you credit or any way I can thank you for helping me?

Comment: @RemoHernandez, I have morphed the comment into an answer you can accept as it seems the suggested approach solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I first commented, one approach to store data from the nested grouping is to use some XML structure to store it instead of outputting it directly as text, then you can easily use `sum` on data in intermediary XML structure and of course output the other data as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" 
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/bsvc">
    <xsl:output indent="no" method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">
        <header>
            <xsl:text>Account</xsl:text><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Department</xsl:text><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Amount</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </header>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry[ wd:Earning_Code != 'FLSA-01']" group-by="wd:Department">
                    <xsl:variable name="Department" select="current-grouping-key()"/>

                    <xsl:variable name="groups">
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="wd:Ledger_ID">

                            <group>
                                <ledger-id>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                                </ledger-id>
                                <department>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$Department"/>
                                </department>


                            <!-- The Department on the wd:Earning_Code = 'FLSA-01' is incorrect. I will sum FLSA and OT amount, then divide by the OT hours. Tie back using OT department.-->

                            <!-- Sum of OT hours by Position -->
                            <xsl:variable name="SumOfOvertimeHours" select="sum(../wd:Report_Entry[wd:Earning_Code = 'OT'  and wd:Position = current-group()/wd:Position]/wd:Total_PayLine_hours)"/>

                            <!-- To get the Sum Amount of OT and FLSA by position-->
                            <xsl:variable name="OverTimeandFLSAAmount" select="sum(../wd:Report_Entry[(wd:Ledger_ID = '2325' or wd:Ledger_ID  ='2387') and (wd:Position = current-group()/wd:Position) ]/wd:Transaction_Amount )"/>

                            <!-- To get Hourly Rate for all of Overtime and FLSA-->
                            <xsl:variable name="OTHourlyRate" select="$OverTimeandFLSAAmount div $SumOfOvertimeHours"/>

                            <!-- To get the Sum of OT and FLSA to tie Department. Use Hourly rate * hours from OT-->
                            <xsl:variable name="LedgerAmount" select="format-number($OTHourlyRate * sum(current-group()[wd:Earning_Code = 'OT']/wd:Total_PayLine_hours),'##.00')"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$LedgerAmount"/>
                               <ledger-amount>
                                   <xsl:value-of select="$LedgerAmount"/>
                               </ledger-amount>
                            </group>

                        </xsl:for-each-group>    
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$groups/group/string-join(*, '|')" separator="&#10;"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

<!-- *****************************************************Offset************************************************************************************** -->                
                            <!-- Ledger ID --><xsl:text>Balance</xsl:text><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                            <!-- Dept ID --><xsl:value-of select="$Department"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>

                             <!-- Sum of OT hours by Position -->
                             <xsl:variable name="SumOfOTHours" select="sum(../wd:Report_Entry[wd:Earning_Code = 'OT'  and wd:Position = current-group()/wd:Position]/wd:Total_PayLine_hours)"/>

                            <!-- Sum of OT and FLSA amount by Position -->
                            <xsl:variable name="SumOfOTandFLSAAmount" select="sum(../wd:Report_Entry[( (wd:Ledger_ID = '2387' or wd:Ledger_ID = '2325' )  and wd:Position = current-group()/wd:Position)]/wd:Transaction_Amount)"/>

                            <!-- To get Hourly Rate for all of Overtime and FLSA-->
                            <xsl:variable name="OTHourlyRate" select="$SumOfOTandFLSAAmount div $SumOfOTHours"/>

                            <!-- To get the Sum of OT and FLSA to tie Department. Use Hourly rate * hours from OT-->
                            <xsl:value-of select="sum($groups/group/ledger-amount)"/>

                            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>               
                </xsl:for-each-group>  
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUw.